# Purpose of unused signal/vias

Tags: layout, flash, via

I'm working on a layout where I have to replace a QSPI flash memory (EPCQ-L1256) to account for obsoleteness. As shown on on the schematic below, only the power, clk, data, and chip select signals are used to connect the flash to an FPGA.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Looking at the previous layout/footprint, I noticed that there were traces routed to that connect unused signals to vias. The packaging is a BGA.

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Why are these vias here if they are not used to route signals to different layers?

Comment: Probably test points.

Comment: Probably "just in case" vias - without them the balls are forever unreachable. If some new chip comes along with a new pin, or there's a schematic mistake, an extra via may bail you out. But, they do percolate the ground and power planes and make it harder to mount decoupling caps, so best left out if you're sure pins are NC and will stay that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<I realized my “comment” was more like an “answer” so providing it here as an answer in hopes it will be accepted and this doesn’t come back as an annoying zombie “community bot” re-post in five years.>

I suspect these vias were added “just in case” a ball needed to be accessed.

Reasons you might want that hedge:

- schematic or footprint might be wrong
- a new version of the chip comes along in the same package but uses a
  previously unused pin
- a second source vendor has the same part but requires a particular
  pin to be pulled up/down
- in these cases a rework wire salvages the board – make it permanent
  with the next board spin

Reasons you might want to avoid adding those vias:

- they end up percolating all layers under the BGA
- these holes impinge on power/ground quality and limit routing channels
- they make it harder to fit decoupling caps under the BGA or force
  extra small packaging for them

So if you’re really conservative, you’d want to add the vias to bail you out in case of disaster.

But if you’re really conservative, you’d want to take them out to maximize signal integrity!

Comment: Thank you. These are some good techniques for PCB design.